# Error opening PPT in win32com convert ppt to images

Tags: python-3.x, win32com, python-pptx

I need to convert 300+ slides to images,

below code i found from a question

```
Application = win32com.client.Dispatch("PowerPoint.Application")
Presentation = Application.Presentations.Open(r"D://HSK1.pptx")
Presentation.Slides[1].Export(r"D://e.jpg", "JPG")
Application.Quit()
Presentation = None
Application = None
```

But I am getting this error

```
        Presentation.Slides[0].Export(r"D://e.jpg", "JPG")
  File "<COMObject <unknown>>", line 2, in Export
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, 'Microsoft PowerPoint', "Slide.Export : PowerPoint can't save ^0 to ^1.", '', 0, -2147467259), None)
```

error is unclear and i can not understand it.

Comment: It is likely you need a full path to your file?

Comment: code and file are in the same place.

Comment: Your code isn't opening the file: Powerpoint is. Which directory does Powerpoint consider to be the default though? The Powerpoint application object won't know the working directory of the calling code (with COM it might not even be on the same machine). When I open Powerpoint it defaults to the Documents folder of the logged-on user for example. You could at least try putting in the full path and see what happens ...

Comment: it makes sense. thanks for the explanation. I try and update.

Answer (score 0):

Powerpoint cannot find the file: add the full path.

Use this code to check what the error means:

```
import win32com.client as wc
import pywintypes
import win32api

app = wc.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Powerpoint.Application')

try:
    app.Presentations.Open('SomeMissingFile.pptx')
except pywintypes.com_error as err:
    print(err)
    info = err.excepinfo[5]
    errstring = win32api.FormatMessage(info)
    print('Message: ',errstring)
```

The result you get if Powerpoint can't find the file:

```
(-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, None, None, None, 0, -2147024894), None)
Message:  The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Comment: yes it was a path error. but now i am getting a new error. this library errors are so strange.